# Can't use '\1' backreference to capture-group in a function call in re.sub() repr expression

Tags: python, regex, substitution, backreference, capture-group

I have a string `S = '02143'` and a list `A = ['a','b','c','d','e']`. I want to replace all those digits in 'S' with their corresponding element in list `A`.

For example, replace `0` with `A[0]`, `2` with `A[2]` and so on. Final output should be `S = 'acbed'`.

I tried:

```
S = re.sub(r'([0-9])', A[int(r'\g<1>')], S)
```

However this gives an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\g<1>'`. I guess it is considering backreference `'\g<1>'` as a string. How can I solve this especially using `re.sub` and capture-groups, else alternatively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the `re.sub(r'([0-9])',A[int(r'\g<1>')],S)` does not work is that `\g<1>` (which is an unambiguous representation of the first backreference otherwise written as `\1`) backreference only works when used in the *string replacement pattern*. If you pass it to another method, it will "see" just `\g<1>` literal string, since the `re` module won't have any chance of evaluating it at that time. `re` engine only evaluates it during a match, but the `A[int(r'\g<1>')]` part is evaluated before the `re` engine attempts to find a match.

That is why it is made possible to use callback methods inside [**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) as the replacement argument: you may pass the matched group values to any external methods for advanced manipulation.

See the [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
> occurrence of `pattern`. The function takes a single match object
> argument, and returns the replacement string.

Use

```
import re
S = '02143' 
A = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print(re.sub(r'[0-9]',lambda x: A[int(x.group())],S))
```

See the [Python demo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Note you do not need to *capture* the whole pattern with parentheses, you can access the whole match with `x.group()`.